# Cordova build failing , but works in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am building my sample app project from eclipse and it works fine, but when I am trying to build it from Cordova CLI , it is giving me below error

```
 -code-gen: [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one. [mergemanifest] Manifest
 merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
      [echo] Handling aidl files...
      [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
      [echo] ----------
      [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
      [echo] ----------
      [echo] Handling Resources...
      [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
      [aapt] invalid resource directory name: C:\SampleApp\SampleApp\platforms\android\android-sam-lib_10.1.0.1312\bin\res/crunch

 BUILD FAILED C:\Tools\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The
 following error occurred while executing this line :
 C:\Tools\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1

 Total time: 2 seconds

 C:\SampleApp\SampleApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                     throw e;
                           ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\SampleApp\SampleApp\platforms\android
 \build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen Error:
 C:\SampleApp\SampleApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command
 failed with exit code 8
     at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\c
 ordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
     at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```